# Posted parameters always empty from view to controller in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have got a problem to get back a parameter from my view to my controller with MVC4.

This is my model's classes (sorry for all this code, I wanted to post an image at first but I'm too newbie to be allowed to to that):

```
    public class Form
{
    public Form()
    {
        this.Rows = new List<Row>();
    }

    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Row
{
    protected Row()
    {
        this.Label = string.Empty;
        this.Type = string.Empty;
    }

    public string Label { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}

    public class SimpleRow : Row
{

    public SimpleRow()
    {
        this.Value = string.Empty;
    }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}

    public class CheckRow : Row
{
    public CheckRow()
    {
        this.CheckedItems = new List<CheckedItem>();
        this.Id = 0;
    }

    public List<CheckedItem> CheckedItems { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}

    public class CheckedItem
{
    public CheckedItem()
    {
        this.Title = string.Empty;
        this.Checked = false;
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

I managed to build my view from an input xml file which is the serialization of my model.
But my problem is, when I change some value in my view and push the save button, i get back an empty parameter in my controller function.

The controller :

```
public class FormController : Controller
{
    // GET: /Form/
    #region Public Methods and Operators

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        this.ViewBag.Title = "Formulaire Collaborateur";

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            return this.View(SerialisationHelper.DeserializeFromStream<Form>(file.InputStream));
        }

        return this.View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult EmailForm(Form updatedForm)
    {
        Form f = updatedForm;  // Empty instance of Form       

        return this.View("Index");
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And my view :

```
@model Form
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("EmailForm", "Form", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<fieldset>
       @foreach (var row in Model.Rows)
    {
        @Html.Partial("Row", row)
    }
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
<br />
}
```

This view calls the other view associated to my model classes.

If you need more code I will post it.
And, please, excuse my english, I'm not a native speaker.

Florent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear from your code what are you doing in `@Html.Partial("Row", row)` But anyway you should make a [EditorTemplate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx) for this `Row` type then just use it :

```
@foreach (var row in Model.Rows)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m=>row)
}
```

Comment: In fact I'm using @Html.Partial() because in my others views I have got cshtml code. When I put an @Html.EditorFor() it just put the name of my properties as label ans the value of those properties in text box instead of the cshtml presentation I had code. If you think it would be better to post this views code for the clarity of my question I can do it.

Comment: I managed to make it works. Thanks to you, the EditorFor thing gave me a lead to finally find the solution. It was a misunderstanding on how work MVC4 with complex data model. Thank you

Comment: hello, I am not familiar with StackOverflow tools, and I apologized for the time I took to accept your answer.
I was a bit busy these days but I will post my solution soon.